# Jsoup SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, jsoup

I get a `SocketTimeoutException` when I try to parse a lot of HTML documents using Jsoup.

For example, I got a list of links :

```html
<a href="www.domain.com/url1.html">link1</a>
<a href="www.domain.com/url2.html">link2</a>
<a href="www.domain.com/url3.html">link3</a>
<a href="www.domain.com/url4.html">link4</a>
```

For each link, I parse the document linked to the URL (from the href attribute) to get other pieces of information in those pages.

So I can imagine that it takes lot of time, but how to shut off this exception Here is the whole stack trace:

```java
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:381)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:364)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:143)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:132)
    at app.ForumCrawler.crawl(ForumCrawler.java:50)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: The code you added in your edit sets the timeout to infinite. This is undesirable in most use cases. It is much better to use a specific timeout as indicated in MarcoS answer, even if the timeout is long.

Comment: I guess the `timeout(0)` will make Jsoup connect the url again and again until it connect.

Comment: This seems to be a solution found by Question author [C. Maillard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817143) `Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).get();` as per [earlier revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6571548/6)

Answer (score 149):

I think you can do

```
Jsoup.connect("...").timeout(10 * 1000).get();
```

which sets timeout to 10s.

Comment: 121 upvotes but no explanation of why this fixes the issue? Why does that address the problem when the default is, it would appear, 30 seconds?

Comment: @AlanHay my answer was suggesting to solve the problem by setting a timeout, not by using that specific value as a timeout :)

Comment: @AlanHay, the default timeout when the Q & A were written was 3 seconds. So any increase would have lowered the socket timeout frequency and helped to fix the issue. I updated the default to 30 seconds in 2016.

Answer (score 27):

Ok - so, I tried to offer this as an edit to MarcoS's answer, but the edit was rejected. Nevertheless, the following information may be useful to future visitors:

According to the [javadocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout%28int%29), the default [timeout](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#timeout-int-) for an `org.jsoup.Connection` is 30 seconds.

As has already been mentioned, this can be set using `timeout(int millis)`

Also, as the OP notes in the edit, this can also be set using `timeout(0)`. However, as the javadocs state:

> A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout.

Comment: Setting an infinite timeout is a bad idea in most cases. Use a long timeout, but always specify one. See MarcoS answer.

Comment: @stepanian - to be clear, I'm not advocating setting an infinite timeout. This had been suggested as the solution by the OP, although I wanted to direct future users to the implications of this. Indeed, when I originally posted my 'answer', I indicated that I thought it should have been an edit to MacroS's answer, as there was some additional information that might be useful to future users... but the edit was rejected.

Comment: The default timeout is not 3 seconds, but 30 seconds (30000 millis), you can see it in https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html

Comment: The timeout used to be 3 seconds, back when the question was written.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
```

and only setting `.userAgent(Opera)` worked for me.

So I used [`Connection userAgent(String userAgent)`](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/jsoup-set-user-agent-example/760) method of Connection class to set Jsoup user agent.

Something like:

```
Jsoup.connect("link").userAgent("Opera").get();
```

Answer (score 2):

There is mistake on https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html.
Default timeout is not 30 seconds. It is 3 seconds.
Just look at javadoc in codes. It says 3000 ms.

Comment: On java doc: "The default timeout is 30 seconds (30,000 millis). A timeout of zero is treated as an infinite timeout." https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html

Answer (score -1):

This should work:
`Jsoup.connect(url.toLowerCase()).timeout(0);`.

Answer (score -6):

Set timeout while connecting from jsoup.

Comment: Please add futher info about your answer

Comment: Please support your answer with explanations and code snippets if necessary.