# SocketTimeoutException when parsing website (HW)

Tags: java, jsoup, socket-timeout-exception

We are learning to use JSOUP and urlconnection so we are parsing pages from a website of our choosing and parsing the pages to answer interesting questions.

Everything works well, however every now an then I get a SocketTimeOutException. I think this is because the website disconnects my program (or times me out, or throttles, or something).

I have implemented a random sleep between 0-30 seconds every time a new page is downloaded. and I think it helps but it still happens. So now I try to catch the exception and sleep for 15 minutes before recursively trying again.

Is there a better way to handle this? Is this the reason I am getting the exception?

Also, would it help to change IP somehow every few minutes (and is that possible in Java)?
Thanks

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571548/i-get-a-sockettimeoutexception-in-jsoup-read-timed-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works well, however every now an then I get a `SocketTimeOutException`. I think this is because the website disconnects my program (or times me out, or throttles, or something).

Connection failing in HTTP is **expected**. That's the nature of the protocol. There can be many reasons for that (your newtork is unstable, their network is unstable, their firewall thinks you're attacking them and blocks, YOUR firewall thinks you're under attack and blocks).

> I have implemented a random sleep between 0-30 seconds every time a new page is downloaded. and I think it helps but it still happens. So now I try to catch the exception and sleep for 15 minutes before recursively trying again.

I'd sleep everytime I sucessfully get a page OR everytime there is an error and then retry. I wouldn't wait so much, though (15mins?), I'd make it 1min tops for both.

> Is there a better way to handle this? Is this the reason I am getting the exception?

As said, you get the exception due to the network. There's nothing you can do about it, this is normal network behavior.

> Also, would it help to change IP somehow every few minutes (and is that possible in Java)?

Would help if the target website does some kind of logging and blocks an IP address after `n` requests. Still, you can't change it the way you want it through Java. The IP address belongs to the **machine** (not the program) and most of the time is assigned by somebody else, not you.

You could make the HTTP requests through proxies, and then their IP addresses is what will reach the target server (and you would change the proxy when one gets banned), but this will make your connection even more unstable, since you are adding one more layer on the "transaction".

Comment: very helpful, thank you. Do you think the random sleep (30) seconds is also too much? SHould I just do a random 10 second (recursively). Also what about VPN, wouldn't that "change" my IP in the webpage eyes?

Comment: Look, if you are *sleeping* to avoid getting blocked, the amount will highly depend on the target's website configs. (If they block someone that makes more than one request per minute, you'd want to sleep one minute between requests, of course). But if you are sleeping just because of the "unstability", then 10 seconds is pretty much OK.

Comment: About the VPN, it *could* change your IP (ultimately, we can't say for sure, as we don't know for a fact how you network is configured), but you will still have the same IP everytime you make the request. If the target site blocks IPs based on the number of requests, then there's no gain on using a VPN (you'd get blocked the same way). Unless... you have a lot of VPNs and keep changing them (like I said with proxies at the end of the answer).